# Android Vision Camera set image size

Tags: xamarin.android, google-vision

I am using `Android Vision` Camera in a `Xamarin.Android` app. Is their any way we can set the image size say 32 * 32 pixels taken by the camera not the preview size.

Comment: I m not sure I understand, are you asking if its possible to resize the picture?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [CameraSource.PictureCallback](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/CameraSource.PictureCallback), convert the byte array to a bitmap using [BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray(byte[],%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options)) in combination with [BitmapFactory.Options](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html)